# list comprehension selected indexes

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a file like this (pretend it were a matrix):

```
abcde
fghik
lmnop
```

I want to put this in a 2d list but with only columns up to index 3:

```
 #  0   1   2   3
 [['a','b','c','d'],
  ['f','g','h','i'],
  ['l','m','n','o']]
```

How does one do this using a list comprehension? I know I could loop, but I'm looking for a cleaner way.

```
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
matrix = [[a for a in b] for b in lines] # this gets all columns, up to 4
```

I could also use enumerate/if in the inner list comprehension to check for column. Is that the cleanest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this should work (but perhaps I'm over simplifying). Note the [:4] in the inner comprehension:

```
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
matrix = [[a for a in b[:4]] for b in lines] # this gets all columns, up to 4
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Forgot about slicing!

Answer (score 3):

Slice each line up to the 3th column: `matrix = [[a for a in b][:3] for b in lines]`

Comment: better still: `matrix = [b[:3] for b in lines]`

Comment: The will give you a list of strings though, not a list of lists.

Comment: You can just do `list(b[:3])` (or at least move the `[:3]` inside the listcomp, to `b` so you don't replicate the rest of `b`).

Comment: ok: `separator=' ' # or '\t' or....; matrix = [b.split(separator)[:3] for b in lines`

Answer (score 2):

"but with only columns up to 3"? What is this supposed to mean? Based on your example, do you mean "only the first four columns"? If that's the case, simple:

```
with f as open('file.txt'):
    matrix = [list(line[:4]) for line in f]
```

Calling `readlines` is unnecessary (worse, harmful as it consumes much memory for large files), you can iterate the lines just file.

Comment: Sorry, the columns were zero-indexed. Thanks for the tip on readlines, I will keep it in mind (though for my problem it no issue).

Comment: @Jasie: It may not be an issue now, but you never know how things could change in the future ;) Also, the code is *shorter* and *more readable* this way - there's very very rarely a reason to use `readlines` (and even then, `list(file)` does the same thing).

Comment: I see. Is there an efficiency difference between `list(file)` and `readlines()`?

Comment: @Jasie: I wouldn't know. I never measured it, and I don't care to until you show me how my application is unresponsive because of this ;) Both should use simiar buffering etc, so differences should be negible.